# Why field change in djnago import export doesn't work?

Tags: django, django-import-export

I need to import ManyToMany relationships not by the id field, but by the `number`(from class Part) field. I know that this is done using through_fields, but I do not fully understand how to do it

I need to determine by number field instead of id
\

[image: 1]

`models.py`

```
class Part(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField('Производитель', max_length=100, blank=True)
    number = models.CharField('Артикул', max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField('Комментарий', blank=True, max_length=5000)
    analog = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='ContactConnection',blank=True, related_name='AnalogParts')
    images = models.FileField('Главное изображение', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images0 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images1 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images2 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Запчасть'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Запчасти'

class PartConnection(models.Model):
    to_part = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_parts')
    from_part = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='from_parts')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done specifying the `primary_key=True` option in the field itself. You'll likely want to define it like this;

```
number = models.CharField('Артикул', max_length=100, unique=True, primary_key=True)
```

This will now grant you access to the `number` with `instance.pk`
If you want it to be called id, you just add it like this;

```
id = models.CharField('Артикул', max_length=100, unique=True, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: 'number' cannot be specified for Part model form as it is a non-editable field

Comment: `related_name has no effect on manytomany with a symmetrical relationship`

Comment: Yes, `related_name` is not needed in ManyToMany fields relating to a symm. relationship. This is just a warning, warning you that `related_name` will not be used. Take out the `related_name="AnalogParts"`

Comment: but when i try to import 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/django/django_venv/src/django-import-export/import_export/resources.py", line 661, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
...
import_id_fields = [
File "/home/django/django_venv/src/django-import-export/import_export/resources.py", line 341, in <listcomp>
self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()
KeyError: 'id`

Comment: Yes, ID does not exist anymore, because you now redefined `number` as your id field. You will need to edit everything that calls `id` on your model, or change the variable name of `number` into `id`. It's generally better to use `mymodel.pk`, instead of `mymodel.id`, exactly for this reason. @КанистраКанистрова