# How to relationship such a connection in django?

Tags: django, many-to-many

I need to implement a "end-to-end" connection between products.

like this:

[image: like this]

I automatically put down two-way links between two products. But when I link product A to product B and product B to product C, there is no connection between A and C. It is necessary that they communicate themselves when putting down the two previous links.

`Models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Part(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField('Производитель', max_length=100, blank=True)
    number = models.CharField('Артикул', max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField('Комментарий', blank=True, max_length=5000)
    analog = models.ManyToManyField('self',blank=True, related_name='AnalogParts')
    images = models.FileField('Главное изображение', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images0 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images1 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images2 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Запчасть'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Запчасти'
```

Comment: Didn't you have this setup with PartConnection in here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73454381/why-field-change-in-djnago-import-export-doesnt-work/73455452

Comment: @nigel239 no or it just doesnt work xD

Comment: @nigel239 this should work with signals and post_save

Comment: Alrighty, I don't really understand the question. Can you type out the query you want to create? Or what you want to do?

Comment: @nigel239 I have a lot of goods between which there should be a connection. I need to make it so that instead of putting down all the spare parts every time, put one and the rest attached to it too (quite desolate, but I don’t know how to convey the idea in another way)
In other words, in the picture 3 parts A B C arrows are links. It is necessary that when putting down the red links, the green one would appear by itself

Comment: `class PartConnection(models.Model): parts = models.ManyToManyField(...)`, you can then query with `PartConnection.objects.filter(parts__name=this_is_my_part)`, Then you can get all parts with `partconnection_instance.parts.all()`

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram looks like `Part`s are connected linear. The easiest way to accomplish that is to add `OneToOneField`s to the model it self like so:

```
next = models.OneToOneField('self', related_name='previous', null=True)
```

Then you can do something like

```
part = Part.object.get(name='wheel')
while part.next:
    part = part.next
# At this point Part is the last part in the row
print(part)
```

This is the most easy way. Depending whether you have linear connections between parts only you have to adjust your fields. There is no solution to all of the graph problems unless you realize some graph structure/database which will solve common problems (I think GraphQL can do such stuff, but iam not sure). Also keep in mind that this will most probably execute one SQL query per loop iteration.